# How to use python installed modules (Dex tool)

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to Install Dex tool (Dex is an python tool, used to analyze index performance for mongoDB).

I have installed Python 2.7, and installed Dex tool using following command.

```
pip install dex
```

Dex tool installed successfully.

Now my question is how could i use Dex tool, if i am trying to execute the below query

```
dex -f /data/MongoLog.txt localhost
```

It throwing an error " dex is not recognized as an internal or external command".

How could i solve the error, if there is anything need to do after installing dex tool?

Comment: Your error is saying `dex` but you have said you are using `Dex`. Are you sure you used `Dex` and not `dex` for the command?

Comment: Here is an dex website, https://github.com/mongolab/dex/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all sorry for asking invalid question, because Dex tool is not supporting Windows OS. I am now able to run Dex tool successfully in Ubuntu OS. (This comes to know after 1 week communication with Support center).

Thanks,

Selvakumar S